# Regarding Eclipse Command Frame Work

Tags: swt, eclipse-rap

We are developing a RAP(Rich Ajax Platform) application using Helios 3.6 Version of Eclipse.Here, we are using Command Framework which uses Eclipse Modeling Frame Work.
When a command gets executed ,getMostAffectedObject() returns us the most recently affected Model Object that got modified due to the execution of command.
My question is "How's the most recently changed changed Model object identified by command framework " ?
Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which model objects are affected is implemented in the command itself.

e.g. take a look at the following classes:

```
org.eclipse.emf.edit.command.AddCommand.doGetAffectedObjects()
org.eclipse.emf.edit.command.SetCommand.doGetAffectedObjects()
```